Ph sensor always showing "0" but only in this specific code
I got this school project and I made this simple code linked with a google sheet, the thing is one sensor is giving me the correct reading while the other one only shows "0"
The sensor itself is working, the wiring is okay and it's well calibrated. I already used only the ph part of the code to see the readings and that indeed worked, showing different values above 0
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "time.h"
#include <ESP_Google_Sheet_Client.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <GS_SDHelper.h>

#define WIFI_SSID "Sample"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "Sample123"
#define PROJECT_ID "SampleIDLOL"
#define CLIENT_EMAIL "SampleMailLOL"

const char PRIVATE_KEY[] PROGMEM = "SampleKeyLOL";
const char spreadsheetId[] = "SampleIDLOL";
unsigned long lastTime = 0;  
unsigned long timerDelay = 30000;

void tokenStatusCallback(TokenInfo info);

int phpin = 4;
int tempPin = 5;
int redPin = 18;
int greenPin = 19;
int bluePin = 21;
int buzzer = 13;
float calibrationFactor = 3.5;
float offset = 0.0

OneWire oneWireObjeto(tempPin);
DallasTemperature sensorDS18B20(&oneWireObjeto);

const char* ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org";
unsigned long epochTime; 

unsigned long getTime() {
    time_t now;
    struct tm timeinfo;
    if (!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)) {
        //Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
        return(0);
    }
    time(&now);
    return now;
}

void setup() {
    pinMode(phpin,INPUT);
    pinMode(tempPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(bluePin, OUTPUT);

    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();

    configTime(-18000, 0, ntpServer);

    GSheet.printf("ESP Google Sheet Client v%s\n\n", ESP_GOOGLE_SHEET_CLIENT_VERSION);

    WiFi.setAutoReconnect(true);
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  
    Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(1000);
    }
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println();

    GSheet.setTokenCallback(tokenStatusCallback);
    GSheet.setPrerefreshSeconds(10 * 60);
    GSheet.begin(CLIENT_EMAIL, PROJECT_ID, PRIVATE_KEY);
    
    sensorDS18B20.begin();
}

void loop() {
    sensorDS18B20.requestTemperatures();
    float temperature = (sensorDS18B20.getTempCByIndex(0));   

    int rawValue = analogRead(phpin);
  
    float voltage = (rawValue * 5.0) / 10230.;
    float phValue = (voltage * calibrationFactor) + offset;

    bool ready = GSheet.ready();

    if (ready && millis() - lastTime > timerDelay) {
        lastTime = millis();

        FirebaseJson response;

        Serial.println("\nAppend spreadsheet values...");
        Serial.println("----------------------------");

        FirebaseJson valueRange;
     
        epochTime = getTime();

        valueRange.add("majorDimension", "COLUMNS");
        valueRange.set("values/[0]/[0]", epochTime);
        valueRange.set("values/[1]/[0]", phValue);
        valueRange.set("values/[2]/[0]", temperature);
        
        bool success = GSheet.values.append(&response /* returned response */, spreadsheetId /* spreadsheet Id to append */, "A3" /* range to append */, &valueRange /* data range to append */);
        if (success) {
            response.toString(Serial, true);
            valueRange.clear();
        }
        else {
            Serial.println(GSheet.errorReason());
        }
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());
    }

    if (phValue >= 7) { 
        digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);    
        digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);  
        digitalWrite(bluePin, HIGH);  
        digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);      
    }
    if (phValue >= 3 && phValue < 7) {   
        digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);    
        digitalWrite(greenPin,LOW);   
        digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);   
    }
    if (phValue >= 0 && phValue < 3) {      
        digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);     
        digitalWrite(greenPin, LOW);    
        digitalWrite(bluePin, LOW);     
    }    
    if (phValue > 6.5) {
        digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    }
}

void tokenStatusCallback(TokenInfo info) {
    if (info.status == token_status_error) {
        GSheet.printf("Token info: type = %s, status = %s\n", GSheet.getTokenType(info).c_str(), GSheet.getTokenStatus(info).c_str());
        GSheet.printf("Token error: %s\n", GSheet.getTokenError(info).c_str());
    }
    else {
        GSheet.printf("Token info: type = %s, status = %s\n", GSheet.getTokenType(info).c_str(), GSheet.getTokenStatus(info).c_str());
    }
}

The code for the google sheet works well, the other sensor readings show well along with the epoch time.
The ph readings shows "0" everytime, not only in the google sheet but also in the serial monitor if I include it
Edit: Somehow it was the wifi component, lol. Changing the sensor pin fixed the problem tho

Totally unrelated: Your life may be a happier one if you make all of those globals const or constexpr. For example, int phpin = 4; isn't going to change, so you might as well build in nice compiler errors to help you out should it accidentally be changed by misadventure AND get some potential performance improvements the compiler can take advantage if it knows the value will never change.

Recommendation: Snoop in with a debugger or print out rawValue, voltage, calibrationFactor, and offset to make certain you are not getting any surprises along the way. For example, if rawValue is zero, that casts a bad light on analogRead(phpin).

It's nitpicky, but your indentation is all over the place. Be nice to yourself and use consistent formatting.

^ Some families of bugs are visible as irregularities in the code. Regular code makes these mistakes impossible or obvious.

There is a typo in the voltage formula: 10230. instead of 1023.0

Which side is making problems, reading the sensor or putting data into the spreadsheet? A good approach to solving problems is to reduce their scope, in this context it would be to extract a [mcve], which is also why it's required here on SO. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

You need to use a different GPIO pin for the pH sensor. You're using GPIO4, which is on the ESP32's second analog-to-digital controller (ADC2). ADC2 is unavailable when you're using wifi, as your program does, so calling analogRead() on pin 4 won't work, as you're seeing.
ADC2's GPIO pins are 0, 2, 4, 12, 13, 14, 15, 25, 26, and 27. Don't use those for analog to digital if you're using wifi. You'll need to use one of ADC1's GPIO pins, which are 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39. Pins 34, 35, 36, 37, 38 and 39 are input-only but that shouldn't be a problem for your pH sensor.
Espressif mentions this restriction in their online documentation.

Appart from the many code-styling issues, it looks to me like you have devided by a way-to-large number (float voltage = (rawValue * 5.0) / 10230.: 10230.0. This results in a number which is always between 0 and 1, even after the calibrationfactor and offset added, always turning on your red LED.
In troubleshooting these types of errors, you should print out the value of voltage and pH to see what their values are and how your system is reacting. This will also help you troubleshoot rounding errors when you let the compiler do implicit type-casting from float/double to an integer.

I fixed the typo, and it stills shows only '0', in every input, raw, voltage and ph, all they show me are 0s even when I divide by 1023

Then there is probably something wrong with your pins. Are you 100 percent sure that pin 4 is your analog input? If it still does not work you can use the pin name if it is an Arduino like: analogRead(A4);

It is, as I said once I upload only the sensor reading code it works well, with the same pin number 4, not changing anything. And it is in esp32, I should've said that before

If its esp you really should double check your pins as some are used by wifi; Dont know by heart which ones. EDIT: just saw @romkey 's solution. I think thats what you are looking for
